# Return a graph of a certain type of relationship (with a max-search-depth restriction)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Assuming I have two nodes and want to find a path between them, I can use the following cypher.

```
MATCH(a{ActivityId:"abc"}),(b{ActivityId:"def"}),p=((a)-[x *..15]->(b)) 
return p
```

If I wish to restrict the paths to those with certain attributes e.g. `x.special=true`, how would I achieve this?

Specifically, this query gives me results (without the max-length restriction)

```
MATCH(a{ActivityId:"A3040", ProjectId:"AB.BC"}),(b{ActivityId:"HNP-L0-CON2-A1190",ProjectId:"AB.BC"}),p=((a)-[*{Critical:true}]->(b)) 
RETURN p
```

Whilst this does not

```
MATCH(a{ActivityId:"A3040", ProjectId:"AB.BC"}),(b{ActivityId:"HNP-L0-CON2-A1190",ProjectId:"AB.BC"}),p=((a)-[xs*..15]->(b))
WHERE all(x IN xs WHERE x.Critical)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Are the attributes on nodes or on relationships?

Comment: Attributes ar eon the relationships.  It turns out that I wasn't getting any resuilts because there wasn't a critical path 15 or fewer edges long. Doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`all` predicate](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all) on the relationships:

```
MATCH p=((a {ActivityId: "abc"})-[*..15]->(b {ActivityId:"def"}))
WHERE all(n IN nodes(p) WHERE n.Critical)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks - I updated the question with this attempt (it didn't work when i tried it before posting)

Comment: I updated my answer so that it checks for properties on nodes.

Answer (score 3):

These 3 approaches should all work:

1. ```
   MATCH p=((a {ActivityId: "A3040", ProjectId:"AB.BC"})-[*..15 {Critical: true}]->(b {ActivityId:"HNP-L0-CON2-A1190", ProjectId:"AB.BC"}))
   RETURN p
   ```
2. ```
   MATCH p=((a {ActivityId: "A3040", ProjectId:"AB.BC"})-[*..15]->(b {ActivityId:"HNP-L0-CON2-A1190", ProjectId:"AB.BC"}))
   WHERE ALL(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE r.Critical)
   RETURN p
   ```
3. ```
   MATCH p=((a {ActivityId: "A3040", ProjectId:"AB.BC"})-[xs *..15]->(b {ActivityId:"HNP-L0-CON2-A1190", ProjectId:"AB.BC"}))
   WHERE ALL(r IN xs WHERE r.Critical)
   RETURN p
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`length`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-length) function to filter the results.

> length() returns the length of a path.

```
MATCH (a{ActivityId:"A3040", ProjectId:"AB.BC"})
  ,(b{ActivityId:"HNP-L0-CON2-A1190",ProjectId:"AB.BC"})
  ,p=((a)-[*{Critical:true}]->(b))
WHERE length(p) < 15
RETURN p
```